# NIFI: How to specifiy headers for PublishJMS

Tags: jms, apache-nifi

On NiFi 1.9 - I set up PublishJMS (using the ActiveMQJMSCinnectionFactoryProvider controller service) with the default header variable in the processor config left as .*, but my messages are being sent with no headers and so are being dropped. I have several I added as attributes with names starting with "jms.". How do I configure this so it sends my attributes as headers? Did I miss something?

The property is "Attributes to Send as JMS Headers (Regex)" with a default value of ".*".

Comment: I did some further investigating and it appears that any attribute which contains a dash "-" or a dot "." gets dropped and won't be forwarded as a header. Any thoughts on a work around for this? Is there a library or something I can edit?

Comment: have a look at this escape section - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#escaping

Comment: Working example flow (upload xml as template) - https://gist.github.com/alopresto/aec7eadd2ed8affd7be8e4056699e5f4

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that "." and "-" are illegal characters in the JMS spec so the Publish is correctly enforcing that rule. The processor has a property called "Allow Illegal Characters in Header Names" and is set to a default value of "false". Changing this property to "true" allows the attributes with "." and "-" in the name to be published as headers.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with 1.9.0 version. Since we are upgrading the version to Nifi 1.16.3 and we have created the process and we can able to ignore those special characters to get processed in JMS Header. So this will work with the latest 1.16.3 version